# is flexunit is really required for Flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, flexunit, flexunit4

I have a doubt on Flex unit. Unit test cases are really required for flex application for displaying data.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but I suspect it's because the question isn't very clear and doesn't have an obvious, err, question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you should remember that not everything in Flex is a UI Component.

I, personally, find that FlexUnit (or a unit testing framework) is great for testing services and other non-visual ActionScript / Flex classes.  Was the property set after I set it?  Was the order this ArrayCollection changed after I changed the value of the "orderBy" property on this custom class?  Was my file created after I called a method to create the file?

These are things that unit testing can help answer.

With much of Flex, I find that UI testing, such as FlexMonkey or RIATest is much more applicable.  Did this effect run after I change properties on the ViewStack?  Did the background color change after I clicked this button?  Was the second ComboBox populated with dat after I selected a value in the first Combobo?

these are the sort of questions that User Interface testing can help with.

Comment: It's important to note that the vast majority of Flex developers never write even one unit test, and they believe that this doesn't cause any harm in their projects.  However, I don't know of any studies that have had two teams of developers of exactly the same caliber (if there is any way to determine that) write the same project with and without unit tests to see what the actual practical effect is.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship - I find it frustrating that so many developers still believe unit testing is irrelevant. Have we not got past this argument yet? -> [unit test statistics](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/60505/unit-test-statistics)

Comment: I am a wholehearted proponent of TDD.  However, there _are_ no studies that compare teams of exactly the same caliber building the same project with and withouTDD. From the link you provided "However, case studies cannot be performed with the
rigor of experiments because they involve real people, real projects, and real customers over a relatively long period of time."

Comment: In other words, we "think" TDD decreases development time and defect rates, but it's not 100% proven.